# How can I show Scroll on my UI, with JAVA, SWT?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, scrolledcomposite

I'm trying to put a ScrolledComposite on my UI with SWT.
but now it only shows blank area or something wrong.

The area to show ScrolledComposite is blank without the code,
    "optionCompositeAtLeft.setSize(optionCompositeAtLeft.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT)); "

This is the pic of screenshot.
The optionTab should have the buttons with Scroll....
[image]

and with the code, it shows scroll, but too long height and narrow width.
Somehow, the upper is gone, but come back when I extend the size of window with scroll disappearing.

[image]

I set the color of background red to make it easier to see for you.
Can anyone help me make "optionCompositeAtLeft" filled in ScrolledComposite?
I want the left area of Option tab to be filled with a red background from "optionCompositeAtLef".

Below is my code.

```
private BomCloneDialog dialog = null;
private TabFolder tabFolder = null;
private TabItem tabOption = null;

public CreateOptionTab(TabFolder tabFolder, TabItem tabOption) {
    this.tabFolder = tabFolder;
    this.tabOption = tabOption;
}

public void createOptionTabUI() {
    GridData gdWithFillBoth = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);

    Composite optionComposite = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    optionComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
    tabOption.setControl(optionComposite);

    ScrolledComposite scrolledCompositeForOption = new ScrolledComposite(optionComposite,SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
    scrolledCompositeForOption.setLayoutData(gdWithFillBoth);

    Composite optionCompositeAtLeft = new Composite(scrolledCompositeForOption, SWT.BORDER);
    scrolledCompositeForOption.setContent(optionCompositeAtLeft);
    optionCompositeAtLeft.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
    optionCompositeAtLeft.setLayoutData(gdWithFillBoth);
    optionCompositeAtLeft.setBackground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 255,0,0));

    Button b [] = new Button[30];
    for(int a=0; a<30; a++){
        b[a] = new Button(optionCompositeAtLeft, SWT.PUSH);
        b[a].setText("button"+a);
    }
    **optionCompositeAtLeft.setSize(optionCompositeAtLeft.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));**




    Composite optionButtonComposite = new Composite(optionComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    optionButtonComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
    optionButtonComposite.setLayoutData(gdWithFillBoth);
    Button optionSaveButton = new Button(optionButtonComposite, SWT.NONE);
    optionSaveButton.setLayoutData(gdWithFillBoth);
    optionSaveButton.setText("Save");
    Button optionAddButton = new Button(optionButtonComposite, SWT.NONE);
    optionAddButton.setLayoutData(gdWithFillBoth);
    optionAddButton.setText("Add");

}
```

Comment: I don't get it, what do you mean with "set Vertical Scroll with stable size"?

Comment: sorry that I made you confused, I want the left area of Option tab to be filled with a red background from "optionCompositeAtLef".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure `ScrolledComposite` to resize the content:

```
scrolledCompositeForOption.setExpandHorizontal(true);
scrolledCompositeForOption.setExpandVertical(true);
```

[image: Filled Background]